# vertical alignment in moderncv

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I'm writing my full job application with moderncv.

I don't want to use other classes for the letter, because I can't use the fancy heading of the moderncv title there.

For the letter I need to know how to align a plain-text in centi- or milimeters from the top of the page. With "top of the page" I mean the actual beginnig of the paper, not the geomerty borders or similar.

See picture for detail:

[image]

Thanks for help

**EDIT**
**EDIT**
**EDIT**

because of boobyandbobs problem understanding me, I specify it a litte:

At first you need to know, I'm german.

Germany has a standard for postal mails

This standard demands specifications like, as an example this:

- The creators contact details have to be displayed aligned left and 1.5 centimeters from top of the page
- The date and place from the creation of the letter have to be displayed aligned right and 2.2 centimeters from top

and so on.

See this picture for clearence:

[image]

EDIT EDIT EDIT number 2

Sorry, but this drives me nuts

See MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{fontawesome}  
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\name{{\scshape\Huge My}}{{\scshape Name}}
\address{My street}{12345 There}
\phone[handy]{\faMobile\hspace{2pt}0173\,1111111}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\vspace{1cm}
\color{red}{!This has to be 2.2 centimeter from actual beginning of paper!\color{black}\\

\color{blue}{!This block\\has to be 3.4 centimeter\\from actual beginning of paper!\color{black}\\

\flushright \color{red}{This must be 4.3 centimeter from the top of the paper\color{black}\\
\flushleft
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

MWE looks like:

[image]

Comment: So you need to different vertical space for your text(like in the picture)? Its a bit unclear for me. Otherwise: Does [Changing margins in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12996/124842) help ? For example `top=2cm`?

Comment: see edit, hope it helps. Things like "top=2cm" can't be used, because the displaying of makecvtitle has to start before

Comment: You could try [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170188/124842). But i suggest the handling isen't easy for your solution. A helpful grid to check the distance could be [How can I make a perfect page grid that fits my page...?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229850/124842). For negative spacing you could use [Get width of a given text as length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37294/124842) with [Function determining the length of text...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99242/124842).

Comment: ... i get a solutuon. But its very tricky and i still have problems with the text block(multiple lines, because another anchor with minipage) so its no final answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my first try. As been noted in the commentary its not a optimal solution but maybe it could help a little bit. The lines and margins are just generated optional with `\usepackage{showframe}` and `\showgrid`([Ref. @esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229850/124842) )to see the dimensions, and could bet removed.

**1. Position things absolutely on the page:** Using the helper macros `\AtTextUpperLeft` or `\AtPageUpperLeft` (see `eso-pic)` for easier positioning on the page. Then moved away from `\AtTextUpperLeft` with some horizontal (`\hspace*{<cm>}`) and veritical (`\raisebox{<cm>}{}`) space. To get negative spacing i used `\hspace{0pt-\widthof{<text>}` to get right aligned text.

**2. Length of given text:** The [`calc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package is used to get width of a given text as length.

I used code parts of:

- [@Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170188/124842): using [`eso-pic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic?lang=en) to specific page locations
- [@DavidCarlisle patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99242/124842): to fix a problem using `\widthof`

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.0cm, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{fontawesome}  
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\name{{\scshape\Huge My}}{{\scshape Name}}
\address{My street}{12345 There}
\phone[handy]{\faMobile\hspace{2pt}0173\,1111111}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% code of @https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99242/124842
\makeatletter
\def\@hspace#1{\begingroup\setlength\dimen@{#1}\hskip\dimen@\endgroup}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \showgrid with help of  @https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229850/124842
\newcommand{\showgrid}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
        thin,nodes={font=\fontsize{1}{2}\selectfont},
        yshift=\paperheight% origin is in the upper left corner
        ]
      \draw[gray!25,step=1cm](current page.south west)grid(current page.north east);
      \draw[blue!30!gray,step=10cm](current page.south west) grid(current page.north east);
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmaxstep{\paperwidth/1cm}% calculate needed steps in x direction
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymaxstep{\paperheight/1cm}% calculate needed steps in y direction
      \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\xmaxstep}
        \node [anchor=north] at ([xshift=\step cm]current page.north west) {\step};
      \foreach \step in {0,1,...,\ymaxstep}
        \node [anchor=west] at ([yshift=-\step cm]current page.north west) {\step};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%

%\AtPageUpperLeft{%
%\hspace*{2.5cm}\raisebox{-2.2cm}{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
  \hspace*{0cm}\hspace*{\textwidth}\hspace{0pt-\widthof{Is this okay? ...4.3 centimeter from the top of the paper}}\hspace{2cm-0.81cm}\raisebox{-4.3cm}{%
  \color{red}Is this okay? ...4.3 centimeter from the top of the paper
  }}

\AtTextUpperLeft{%
\hspace*{0cm}\raisebox{-2.2cm}{%
\color{blue}Is this okay? ...2.2 centimeter from the top of the paper
}
}

\AtTextUpperLeft{%
\hspace*{0cm}\raisebox{-3.4cm}{%
\color{blue}
Is this okay? ...3.4 centimeter from the top of the paper ... (single line)
}
}%

\AtTextUpperLeft{%
\hspace*{0cm}\raisebox{-3.87cm}{%
\color{green}
\begin{minipage}{30em}
 Is this okay? ...3.4 centimeter from the top of the paper \\
next line \\
... and ...
\end{minipage}
}}
}%

\showgrid
\makecvtitle
\vspace{1cm}
\flushleft
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bobbyanbob, but the now deleted comment fits it better. The mentioned, german, document (http://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2011_1.pdf) gave me a nice solution on page 30-40.